# Number of edges in graphs having two disjoint cycles of equal length

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

The question is motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246742/prove-a-graph-with-2n-2-edges-has-two-cycles-of-equal-length?rq=1) and [this](http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=Graphs_with_two_edge_disjoint_cycles) two problems.

The first problem states that if $G$ is a graph with $n$ vertices and at least $2n-2$ edges then $G$ must contain two distinct cycles of the same length.

The second problem shows that if $G$ has at least $n+4$ edges then it must contain two disjoint cycles.

My question now is

> **Question.** What would be a lower bound for the number of edges in a graph that would force the graph to contain two disjoint cycles of same length?

By distinct cycles $C_1,C_2$ we mean that $E(C_1) \cap E(C_2) \ne E(C_1) \cup E(C_2)$ and we say that they are disjoint if $E(C_1) \cap E(C_2) = \emptyset$

Comment: A lower bound would be $\frac{n^2+6n+11}{4}$ which ensures that the graph has two disjoint cycles of length $3$: since $m > n^2/4$ the graph contains a triangle. Removing this triangle we get a graph with $n-3$ vertices and at least $\frac{n^2+6n+11}{4} - 3 - 3(n-3) > \frac{(n-3)^2}{4}$ edges hence this graph contains another triangle. I don't suspect this to be optimal though.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it appears that (see [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/vdcycles.pdf&ei=4rkYU43UCYTMygOE54LwAg&usg=AFQjCNGJ5OasP8zA3-DGnN2bXou4hWB8FA&sig2=EHJKh-t0RLnK2Aw-Q1780Q&bvm=bv.62577051,d.bGQ) paper) having $2n$ edges suffices.